How to use ESP12F analog pin to read battery voltage?
I'm using an ESP12F microcontroller powered by a 3.7V battery.
What I want is to get actual information about the battery's state of charge. So to know when the battery needs to recharge.
To achieve this I created a voltage drop from 3.7V to 0.94V (because I read that ADC pin of esp12f operates between 0V - 1V) with 3k and 1k ohm resistors and connected the V out of the voltage drop to the ADC pin. But the analog read is constantly 1024 and doesn't change. When I drop voltage to 0.54V analog read is again 1024. I tried with second esp12f and the result is the same. When I try to read analog value from different components like a temperature sensor it all seems alright - analog value is ~500 and when temp rises the value goes up to ~650. I followed this article about how to read battery voltage but without success. I tried to do the same task with Arduino Uno instead of esp12f and everything works fine.
So based on these tests and observations, I think that there isn't a problem with the circuit because on Arduino Uno works fine, there isn't a problem with esp12f's ADC pin because with the temperature sensor the analog value is accurate.
To summarize: My problem is that the analog value from the battery is constantly 1024 and I can't get actual information about the battery's remaining voltage via esp12f.
In the image below is what my circuit looks like:

And this is the code of how I read the analog value:
const int analogPin = A0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorValue = analogRead(analogPin);
    Serial.print("sensorValue: ");
    Serial.print(sensorValue);

    delay(1000);
}


First some off-topic notes: 1. Commonly you cannot conclude the charge of a rechargeable battery by its voltage. It has a reason why many battery management devices measure the current in and out the battery. 2. The sum resistance is quite low and presumably will discharge your battery more than the rest of your circuit. 3. You might want to add a capacitor in parallel to the low-end resistor to keep the voltage stable while the ADC samples.

Did you check the voltage at the ADC input with a multimeter? Make sure your voltage divider actually works correctly. You can use other voltage sources like a regulated power supply to vary the input voltage. -- Did you check that the selected pin is the same in hardware and software?

It is very odd that you have a measured voltage of 0.54 volts on A0, and still get a reading of 1024. What reading do you get if you take A0 to ground, and what do you get if you leave it floating?

Maximum operating voltage of an ESP8266 is 3.6v (read the datasheet), you can't connect a 3.7V directly to an ESP8266, not mentioned that when the battery is full charged, it could go up to 4.2V.

@hcheung, with a voltage regulator that downs the voltage to 3.3V the result with the reading is the same. I measured battery voltage with a multimeter and it's 3.8V.

@thebusybee, To measure the voltage that goes to ADC with a multimeter I placed + wire of the multimeter at the beginning of the 3k ohm resistor and the - of the multimeter between the two resistors and the output was 0.94V.

@Lee-xp, when A0 is connected to the ground reading is 0 and when I leave it floating reading again is 1024. Based on that is it possible that A0 pin doesn't receive any voltage when is connected to the V out of the voltage divider? But it will be strange because I measured with multimeter the V out value of the voltage divider and it shows 0.97V.

Since nothing seems to make sense here, is there a chance that you might be using something called _VCC build. Apparently '_VCC builds for ESP8266 will internally connect the analog port to the VCC pin of the ESP', though in such a case the output should not be stuck on 1024 - but it is a thought.

What happens if you replace the two resistors with a potentiometer - say a 10k? Then you could read the voltage on the pin when it is grounded (should be zero), and then slowly bring it up. It seems unlikely that the reading will suddenly jump from 0 to 1024. But if it does, the pin is behaving like a digital pin.

So you measured 0.94V across the 3kOhm resistor? This is not the voltage the MCU sees. It sees the voltage across the 1kOhm resistor: 3.8V - 0.94V = 2.86V... -- Please measure the voltage between ADC input and GND. This is what the MCU converts.

@thebusybee makes a good point. And this means that your 1k Ohm resistor is actually around 10K in value. It is very easy to mistake a red band for an orange band on a resistor body. This has got to be the solution surely?

@thebusybee, you were right! I swapped the resistors 1k ohm is the first and 3k ohm is the second. I measured the voltage between ADC pin and GND and now is 0.94V. The analog value I currently read is around ~940. I need to go back and read more about voltage dividers because this was a silly mistake of mine. My next steps will be to add resistors with bigger resistance so the battery won't discharge so fast and try to add a transistor too that will switch on the voltage divider only when I want to measure the battery voltage. Thank you very much both thebusybee and Lee-xp.

As you confirm in a comment, you swapped the resistors. So the ADC input received a voltage too high, and the ADC returned always the maximum value.
With this principle schematic we can calculate the appproximate voltage:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You used R1 = 1kΩ and R2 = 3kΩ, this gives V_ADC = 3.7V *  R2 / (R1 + R2) = 3.7V * 3kΩ / (1kΩ + 3kΩ) = about 2,8V.
With the correct values of R1 = 3kΩ and R2 = 1kΩ it is V_ADC = 3.7V *  R2 / (R1 + R2) = 3.7V * 1kΩ / (3kΩ + 1kΩ) = about 0.9V.
